# Notification when "SO flagged this under review/low quality"?

Tags: support, notifications, low-quality-posts

I just saw that I had this note (SO flagged this under review/low quality) for one of my answers when I checked under Revisions. A users with half the reputation points (ie no more privileges than me) somehow knew this and added some explanatory text.

I have two questions:

- How did this person find out? I didn't get a notification, I would have gladly added to my own question
- Is there a way I can e-mail/send the user a note thanking them for making this initial edit and helping possibly to prevent my answer being deleted?

Did not find answers to this in the FAQ or searching on meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10739190/7) is what you're talking about.

That [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) page lists all sorts of posts that are automatically flagged (first answers/questions, "low  quality" posts, late answers). That user probably saw your question listed in the "low quality" queue (since it was very short), and was nice enough to add a bit of meat to it.
The review link should be directly in the header of the site (near your badges), but I think it might not be visible at certain rep. levels. It becomes available with just 125 rep with the [**vote down**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) privilege.

You can (and should) spend some time in that review page when you have a bit of idle time - you'll spot plenty of content that needs a bit of love (or needs to be flagged/removed).

(You can notify editors of your posts with `@`-comment replies.)

Comment: Thanks .. I had noticed the "review" tab but never looked at it really before. Now that I've looked, I will spend more time in it - from reading more on meta it seems that there's a script that applies heuristics to evaluating answers and that's how they end up on that page - if my understanding is right. I assume other, more "senior" users can probably flag this too.

Comment: Yes, the "low quality" thing is automatic. Posts are rated based on (not fully disclosed) rules that give it a score. Low-score posts appear automatically in Review. This is distinct from posts that are flagged (by other users) as Low Quality. These only show up (afaik) in the Flags page available to 10k users.

Comment: I'm still in the low 3k range, so that also explains why I didn't know, but as you suggested, it might be a good idea to check reviews (not just for my own posts, but to help improve answers in general)

Answer (score 1):

#### How did this person find out?

10k users see when a post has been flagged as low quality, whenever the flag is automatic, or made from another user. They don't see the flags for which the user entered a custom reason.+

#### Is there a way I can e-mail/send the user a note thanking them for making this initial edit and helping possibly to prevent my answer being deleted?

If username edited your post, you can add a comment similar to the following one:

> @username Thank you for your edit.

(The comment is a banal one.)

@-references work also for the users who edited a post. When you reference them in a comment, their name is not auto-completed, but referring them work the same. As usual, if "username" is the username of the editor, you can use *@use* to refer the editor. (You need to use at least 3 characters that are not spaces.)

Comment: Just for people who don't know what banal means, **please don't *actually* leave comments like this!**